# Set custom date format on iOS

Tags: ios, formatting, internationalization

I am using the iOS 9 beta and I am trying to change the date format to
**dayofweek-dayofmonth-month-year**.

For example today would be:

> Tuesday, 25 Aug 2015

In Settings I have looked under ‘Language & Region’, and at the bottom of the page there is something that shows ‘Region Format Example’, but I cannot find a way to set a custom date format without changing my region (which still doesn't allow custom, but it will change it).

Under ‘Date and Time’ there isn't anything either.

Comment: If you’re in the US, check out New Zealand. It also changes the short date format to `d/m/y`, though.

Answer (score 2):

It's currently not possible to set a custom date format on iOS, unlike macOS. On iOS you can only change the date format by changing the region as you discovered.

Comment: Does anyone know which country used the Date format:  m/d/y?  E.g. 9/15/18.  Many thanks.  I tried the UK and Canada, no dice.

Comment: @Penny11 Is the USA m/d/y?

Comment: My bad for not being more specific. If I choose United States, the iPhone uses this format: Sep 17, 2018. Because of screen space limitations, only Sep 17, 20.. is visible. If I could change to a numbers-only format, e.g., 9/17/18, then everything would fit.